# need help regarding ngrx/store

Tags: angular, redux, angular-cli, ngrx

I do know the difference between ngrx/store  and ng2-redux . but angular community pushing for ngrx/store. I have heard that ngrx/store is still have lot of issues and as it is a complete rebuilt and even do not follow the original redux pattern so my question is :  should we use ngrx/store ( not compatible with other redux implementation) OR should we go for ng-redux.    As ng2-redux is built on top of original redux to support angular binding and integration with angular components.

Comment: The answer here is primarily opinion-based, both libraries will deliver a complete feature-set to handle states and state-flow in an angular2-application - it is more a question of philosophy which one you want to choose.

Comment: Thanks . There are few noticeable things as far as compatibility with other redux implementations, and existing issue with ngrs/store goes. If anyone is using ngrx/store and have used ng-redux in the past can share there experience. As I am pretty new to both of these redux framework.

Comment: I've used both - as I said: pretty much anything can be achieved with both and you won't really have a _technical_ difference between the two - it's mostly a different _philosophie or style_

Comment: Embrace the observable pattern, ngrx ftw.

Comment: Thanks, I Will go with ngrx one.